# Copy Windows update to other machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

This question may seem weird, but what I want to do is to download the latest update of windows 7 and apply it to the existing windows 7 virtual machine.

If it's possible, where can I find it, and how do I apply it to the VM?

(This may seem like a weird thing to do, but I'm doing it for a competition called CyberPatriot and I don't want to waste time downloading and updating windows 7.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is find the exact update KB#####(reference) that has the update you would like to apply, download that and put it on a USB drive.

Then, you can force Windows to run the update service through your command prompt to point to that particular update file, and let it run through the Windows update dialog.

This method avoids having to download all the previous updates for Windows 7, while still maintaining a stable Win7 installation on the VM.

Also, you may have to override/adjust some update settings to allow you to only update the 'selected' updates you chose.

edit: The Windows update KB files can be found through the Microsoft website, which allows you to singularly download the update you want.